# Get or access objects from service

Tags: android

From a login activity while pressing a button I run the following service:

```
public class PlayerService extends Service{

    private StorageApi api;
    private String user, password, host = "****";
    private Intent i;

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        i = intent;
        user = intent.getStringExtra("User");
        password = intent.getStringExtra("Pass");

        new connectStorage().execute();

        return startId;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private class connectStorage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                api = DefaultClientFactory.create(host, user, password);
                Log.i("TEST",""+api.getUserInfo());
                return true;
            } catch (StorageApiException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.i("TEST", "" + e.getMessage());

                return false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result == false){
//                progressGenerator.finnish(btnSignIn);
//                btnSignIn.setProgress(-1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid E-mail or Password !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(PlayerService.this, musicPlayer.class);
                myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you see in Asynctask after I connect to api I use

```
            Log.i("TEST",""+api.getUserInfo());
```

getUserInfo method and I get informations like Username, Name, Last Name, E-mail etc...

After doing this this, onPostExecute I switch activity to another screen. My question is, how I can use the API object after connection was initialized and for example get user info on another activity ?

Comment: Simply define your api field as a `public static` field in a helper class - it will then be accessible from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks squonk I think this may be the solution

Comment: @Squonk of course making a variable `public static` would be a solution but i think its not a good solution due to this : it is not a good practice and that it involves risks and limitations like having several instances of the current Activity and get the wrong value from the static variable.

Comment: @Milad : I said use a *helper class* - not an `Activity`.

Comment: @Squonk yes, you are right ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your objects `Parcelable` something like this:

```
ublic class StorageApi implements Parcelable{
    private String userInfo;
...
```

then you must override `writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)` method in that class.

Then you can send your objects to another activity like this:

```
intent.putExtra("api", new StorageApi (api.getUserInfo(), ...));
```

For more info you can take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/how-can-i-make-my-custom-objects-be-parcelable) it will gives you a good example.

Comment: I import this from dependencies, will work only for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the contents of api.getUserInfo() in a string and then pass the string via intent to the activity you would like to switch.
For ex in your code you could write

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result == false){
//                progressGenerator.finnish(btnSignIn);
//                btnSignIn.setProgress(-1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid E-mail or Password !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(PlayerService.this, musicPlayer.class);
                myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                myIntent.putExtra("apiInfo", api.getUserInfo());
                getApplicationContext().startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        }
```

and then in your other activity you can get this api info by

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String apiInfo;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        //If api.getUserInfo() returns a String
        apiInfo = i.getStringExtra("apiInfo");
        //If api.getUserInfo() returns a String Array
        apiInfo = i.getStringArrayExtra("apiInfo");



    }
```